# QGIS slope calculator not producing expected result

Tags: gis, raster, qgis, terrain

I am trying to visualize slope for an elevation raster using QGIS terain analysis tool.  The results are no what I would expect.

Elevation raster is from NASA's [SRTM program](http://www2.jpl.nasa.gov/srtm/).  I picked a relatively mountainous region to run a test [N39W121](http://dds.cr.usgs.gov/srtm/version2_1/SRTM1/Region_01/).

elevation model looks like this

[image]

but resulting slope raster only has two values 0 and 89.9 .
[image]

I used default setting's in QGIS' DEM tool, set to slope mode. Can anyone help me firgure out what I'm doing wrong.  Is it a problem with the original data, or is it settings? I am at a loss. Calculating hillshade and ruggedness index with the same tool produced results as expected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, SRTM's map horizaontal units are in degrees (WGS84), where the vertical units for SRTM is in meters.  This either needs to be compensated for in QGIS's DEM analysis settings or the SRTM raster needs to be converted to a projection that uses meters for its map units.